# Does "this generation" associated with a calendar date identify a generation unambiguously?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

This question arises from the [commentspace in this question on stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136862/is-statistics-mathematics#comment260816_136862).

My comment was:

> Last I checked Terry Tao was the pre-eminent mathematician of this
>   generation?

To which another commenter replied:

> Which generation is that?

Note that I said "**this** generation" as opposed to **our** generation. My question is: does "this generation" associated with a date (timestamp) uniquely identify **a** generation, particularly in the academic context? How else can I identify a generation -- through reference to a specific person?

Comment: If you said ***his*** generation rather than ***this*** generation, the meaning would be quite clear. And it is hard to see how he could be the pre-eminent mathematician of somebody else's generation.

Comment: Are you worried by the ambiguity (span) of "generation"?

Comment: It would be more common to say "his" generation, but "this" generation is also fine. It means *the current* generation, the one ascendant and in control of world affairs. That's different from "our" generation, for example, when it's referenced by, say, [a pair of cranky septuagenarians](http://nathantimmel.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/muppets-waldorf-stadler.jpg).

Comment: @PeterShor Are you then suggesting the use of "**the** generation" in this context? I would argue that that is the same as **this**.

Comment: @anemone Yes, as a side issue, I can't say I am entirely clear on what a generation is, really.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's particularly possible to identify a generation as starting and ending on specific dates, unless you're talking about one particular family tree (in which case, born-adult dates of a single person would probably do).

***His*** generation would certainly be more clear as far as defining what you meant goes, but you could also have defined a time period, for instance the 90's, and that could also go some way in defining a start and end date for a generation.